# Octave Keep String Constant in Equation

Tags: string, octave, equation

In Octave, can I do something like the following:
answer = 'x' + 1

so Octave prints out:
answer = x + 1

In other words, can I keep some variable names as variable names when evaluating an equation?

Answer (score 0):

Just found that this can be done with a Symbolic Match package, such as the Symbolic toolbox:
http://math.digi2.jp/math/octave/forge/